# JavaScript Copy to clipboard works only once

Tags: javascript

Tried to look everywhere, didn't find solution. I am using this JS:

```
function copy(containerid) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    document.getElementById(containerid).style.display = "block";
    range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("Copy");
    document.getElementById(containerid).style.display = "none";
}
```

However using it in my View I can do it either only once or containeid keeps the same value. My View:

```
<input type="text" value="x1" id="x1" style="display:none"><input type="text" value="x2" id="x2" style="display:none">
<img src="~/images/new-post-16.png" onclick="copy('x1')"/> <img src="~/images/phone-30-16.png" onclick="copy('x2')" />
```

I tried to multiply the function and call it only for one element only, but it still copied only one instance, either x1 or after reload of page x2. Any ideas? Elements must be hidden.

Comment: I don’t know this API but I wonder if `window.getSelection().addRange` may have some side effects that are left over after the first call. Calling `window.getSelection().empty()` might help.

Comment: This little tweak works! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following. It works.

```js
function copy(containerid) {   
    var copyDiv = document.getElementById(containerid);
    copyDiv.style.display = 'block';
    copyDiv.focus();
    document.execCommand('SelectAll');
    document.execCommand("Copy", false, null);
    copyDiv.style.display = 'none';
    console.log("Text value copied to clipboard from ID: ", containerid);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="x1" id="x1" style="display: none"><input type="text" value="x2" id="x2" style="display: none">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20x20/ff0000/000000?text=1" onclick="copy('x1')"/> <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20x20/00ff00/000000?text=2" onclick="copy('x2')" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to add a selection to an already existing selection that is in a different control. That's not going to work. You're basically trying to have multi-cursor in two distinct text input.

If you clear your selection with `window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();` just before your `window.getSelection().addRange(range);` it will work.

This is also why @Hari Das code works: `selectAll` **replaces** the selected range, it doesn't try to add it.